# How to sort sql query without primary key?

Tags: mysql, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have table called articles_tags which have two columns:

- article_id
- tag_id

(has_and_belongs_to_many association) (I implemented this with php)

I want to find the last article_id that entered to db, so i tried to do:

```
SELECT `article_id` FROM `articles_tags`  ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

The first problem is that i don't want sort by article_id, and the second one is that it doesn't work.

i think because i don't have primary key in this table.

Comment: yes, i have created_at column in articles table.
you mean to search for last article that have tag? great idea :)

Comment: You can order by any column whether it's the primary key or not. :-)

Comment: In second thought, it's not great idea, because it's not necessary find me the last tagged article

Comment: how are both columns defined?

Comment: @Lieven, int(11) with no extra stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an additional column ... either an autogenerated number or a DaytIme field. Then you can sort. Otherwise you can never assume to get the right record.

Update: doesn't necessarily need to be id field

Comment: +1 Why is this downvoted? AFAIK, it's the only correct answer. A database engine has no notion whatsoever about *what is the last inserted record*. If you need that kind of information, add a timestamp or an ID as suggested by Morten.

Comment: +1 Seems to be the correct answer (I guess I misunderstood the OP).

Answer (score 3):

A simple MAX should suffice:

```
select max(article_id) from articles_tags
```

UPDATE:

To get the article that was last tagged:

```
select article_id from articles_tags where tag_id = 
  (select max(tag_id) from articles_tags)
```

Comment: this solution will not necessary find me the last row entered :/

Comment: True, if article_id is increasing for every new record in the table

Comment: @Yarin: Do you want the article that was last inserted or the article that was last tagged?

Comment: @Morten That's not necessary - in fact, I'd expect several entries per article_id in this table (otherwise, the table doesn't make much sense).

Comment: @Frank: I want the last tagged article.

Comment: @Yarin: I'ved added a 2nd query that returns the last tagged article (assuming tag_ids are always increasing)

Comment: @Frank: tags_ids is increasing, but think if I'm updating old article with old tag, your solution will not give me this article I'm just updated.

Comment: @Yarin Now I'm confused. So you want the article for the last entry in articles_tags, but your tag_id might reference an already existing tag, and your article_id an already existing article? So if someone adds a row to articles_tags whose article existed 1 year ago and whose tag existed 1 year ago, this tuple should be returned by your query? If that's the case, you'll need an additional column (preferably in articles_tags), either a primary key (sensible) or a timestamp.

Comment: @Frank, yeah it should return, i think there is no other way except adding extra column.

Comment: @Yarin Then I suggest you accept Morten's answer, since he understood your problem correctly from the very beginning.